# C translation phases concrete examples

Tags: c

According to the C11 standard (5.1.1.2 Translation phases) there are 8 translation phases.
Can anyone give a concrete example for each of the phases.

For example at phase 1 there is:

> Physical source ﬁle multibyte characters are mapped, in an
>   implementation- deﬁned manner, to the source character set...

so can I have an example of what happens when that mapping is executed and so on
for other phases?

Comment: Most of these phases are fairly self explanatory. Are there any in particular that are confusing?

Comment: Yes, i.e, 1 and 5. Can you give me some concrete examples of multibyte mapping or escape conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Well, one example of phase one would be storing your source code into a record-oriented format, such as in z/OS on the mainframe.

These data sets have fixed record sizes so, if your data set specification was FB80 (fixed, blocked, record length of 80), the "line":

```
int main (void)
```

would be stored as those fifteen characters followed by sixty-five spaces, and *no* newline.

Phase one translation would read in the record, possibly strip off the trailing spaces, and add a newline character, before passing the line on to the next phase.

As per the standard, this is also the phase that handles trigraphs, such as converting `??(` into `[` on a 3270 terminal that has no support for the `[` character.

An example of phase five is if you're writing your code on z/OS (using EBCDIC) but cross-compiling it for Linux/x86 (using ASCII/Unicode).

In that case the source characters within string literals and character constants must have the *ASCII* representation rather than the EBCDIC one. Otherwise, you're likely to get some truly bizarre output on your Linux box.